# How to speed up Spark SQL unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm evaluating Spark SQL to implement a simple reporting module (few simple aggregations over Avro data already stored on HDFS). I have no doubt that Spark SQL could a good fit for both my functional and non-functional requirements.

However, on top of production requirements I want to make sure the module will be testable. We follow a BDD approach with very focused scenarios which means that this module will require to run tens / hundreds of SQL queries over some very simple data (1..10 records).

To get a rough idea of the performance I can expect from Spark SQL in local mode, I have quickly prototyped a few tests:

1. `select count(*) from myTable`
2. `select key, count(*) from myTable group by key`

The first test takes 100ms on average, but the second one takes 500ms. Such performance is unacceptable this it would make the test suite too slow.

For comparison, I can run the same test in 10ms using Crunch and its MemPipeline (1500ms with MRPipeline in local mode) and also 1500ms with Hive in embedded mode. Spark SQL is thus a bit faster than MR in local mode, but still way to slow to build good test suites.

Is it possible to speed up Spark SQL in local mode ?

Is there a better / faster way to test a Spark SQL module ?

(I have not profiled the execution yet but since a `groupBy().countByKey()` on a RDD takes 40ms on average I expect to find that the culprit is the query optimizer)

---

My quick & dirty test code follows:

```
  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[4]")
                .setAppName("poc-sparksql");

  try (JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf)) {
        SQLContext sqlCtx = new SQLContext(ctx);

        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Stopwatch testCaseSw = new Stopwatch().start();

            DataFrame df = sqlCtx.load("/tmp/test.avro", "com.databricks.spark.avro");
            df.registerTempTable("myTable");
            DataFrame result = sqlCtx.sql("select count(*) from myTable");

            System.out.println("Results: " + result.collectAsList());
            System.out.println("Elapsed: " + testCaseSw.elapsedMillis());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Stopwatch testCaseSw = new Stopwatch().start();

            DataFrame df = sqlCtx.load("/tmp/test.avro", "com.databricks.spark.avro");
            df.registerTempTable("myTable");
            DataFrame result = sqlCtx.sql("select a, count(*) from myTable group by a ");

            System.out.println("Results: " + result.collectAsList());
            System.out.println("Elapsed: " + testCaseSw.elapsedMillis());
        }
 }
```

Comment: Did you consider caching?

Comment: If you are testing different queries over same data, load data once.. and then query..

Comment: According to my tests caching does not help (the sql call being the slow thing). I was more thinking about something like being able to disable some optimizations. I don't see caching as a solution because 1- A "good" test has its input designed to make it easy to understand a given behavior, so each test has different input. The sloppy code I provided does not try to mimic what a test suite would do (automatic Avro serialization of a gherkins table etc.) 2- SQL queries being deterministic if input was always the same then I had cache the collected output data rather than the input

Comment: It's been one year, but have you actually found a solution for slow tests that are using .sql() ? If it's the case, could you please share it with us? The initial initialization of spark already takes ~20 seconds in my local environment, but its the tests that are taking all the time (3 minutes).

Comment: Apache Crunch is still a good fit for most things we do and decided to stick to it. Writing some extra code seemed to be a better tradeoff than to understand how to write good test suites with Spark and its "cheap integration tests only" design. I am still interested by this topic, though.

Answer (score 5):

**Launching too many tasks isn't a good option when the data size is really small.** 
 In your second option `group by` will create another `stage` with `200 tasks` because you didn't set shuffle partitions property and, by default it is `200` and most of them would be empty.

It might not make a difference in a single test but can have significant impact when you have thousands of tests with shuffle operations.

Set `"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"` to `x (where x is local[x]`) in spark conf .

*Actually you don't need `4 executors` to handle less than 10 records so better reduce the number of executors to `1` and also set `shuffle.paritions` to `1`.*

Comment: is spark.sql.shuffle.partitions still a parameter? I can't find it in the 2.4.5 doc. I was going to check to verify but I didnt think the shuffle partitions would even be used in local mode.

Comment: I think you can do a couple of joins (or any shuffle operations) and check the partitions (or tasks on UI) of output frame.
Please find this property on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: This sped up my pyspark unittests that were using groupby by a ridiculous amount. Thank you! I used `SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at optimization of ms level there are various pointers.

1. Read your data once and cache and just the SQL query over it multiple times.  inside the loop load means "spawning new Task in everyIteartion"

> ```
>  DataFrame df = sqlCtx.load("/tmp/test.avro","com.databricks.spark.avro");
>  df.registerTempTable("myTable");  
>  df.cache()
>
>  for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
>        Stopwatch testCaseSw = new Stopwatch().start();
>        DataFrame result = sqlCtx.sql("select count(*) from myTable");
>        // Dont do printLn inside the loop , save the output in some hashMap and print it later once the loop is complete
>        System.out.println("Results: " + result.collectAsList());
>        System.out.println("Elapsed: " + testCaseSw.elapsedMillis());
> }
> ```

2. Extract out System.out.println outside the loop as its consuming some time.

Please have a look :
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/understanding-spark-through-map-reduce/

Answer (score 0):

I use [`spark-testing-base`](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base) library developed by Holden Karau for unit-test in Spark.

In the relative `README.md`s you can find further information for tweaking resources to allocate for unit tests.